# Losing data with UDP over WiFi when multicasting

Tags: udp, broadcast

I'm currently working a network protocol which includes a client-to-client system with auto-discovering of clients on the current local network.

Right now, I'm periodically broadsting over `255.255.255.255` and if a client doesn't emit for 30 seconds I consider it dead (then offline). The goal is to keep an up-to-date list of clients runing. It's working well using UDP, but UDP does not ensure that the packets have been sucessfully delivered. So when it comes to the WiFi parts of the network, I sometimes have "false postivives" of dead clients. Currently I've reduced the time between 2 broadcasts to solve the issue (still not working well), but I don't find this clean.

Is there anything I can do to keep a list of "online" clients without this risk of "false positives" ?

Comment: half the time period and run it on TCP

Comment: TCP is an Unicast protocol. Half of the time period is what I currently do, but I want something more reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To minimize the false positives, due to dropped packets you should alter a little bit the logic of your `heartbeat` protocol.

Rather than relying on a single packet broadcast per `N` seconds, you can send a burst 3 or more packets immediately one after the other every `N` seconds. This is an approach that `ping` and `traceroute` tools follow. With this method you decrease significantly the probability of a lost announcement from a peer.

Furthermore, you can specify a certain number of lost announcements that your application can afford. Also, in order to minimize the possibility of packet loss using wireless network, try to minimize as much as possible the size of the broadcast UDP packet.

Comment: It's like having a "rush period" every `N` seconds. Thank you. (I'll give the bounty point as soon as I can).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this over, so you will broadcast "ServerIsUp" message
and every client than can register on server. When client is going offline it will unregister, otherwise you can consider it alive.

Comment: I'm on a client-to-client architecture.